# Mobile Simulator for Windows

Tags: windows, mobile, simulator

I'm developing website for mobile phone and I need software that will simulate experience on mobile phone. Something like SDK for Android.
I've read many articles on this subject, however, most of them are using separate SDKs for each mobile manufacturer (iPhone SDK, Android SDK and so on).
What I need is a software that will simulate all of these devices.
Anyone knows software like this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that such a thing exists.

Bare in mind that you're talking about multiple operating systems (iOS, Android, Symbian, Windows Phone 7, etc) with different languages running browsers from multiple vendors (the native browsers, plus Opera Mini & Opera Mobile, SkyFire, etc) with different combinations of phone models and capabilities. A comprehensive testing application would be an exceedingly complicated beast indeed.

Comment: Yes, I do agree. I'll probably take simple way - just send different UserAgent strings via Browser to Website and test detection. Appearance - I'll just check with hardware I have.

Answer (score 0):

Does [YouWave](http://www.youwave.com/) meet your needs?

As you mentioned, there is Google's Android emulator and Motorola's emulator (MOTODEV) but while they don't need Eclipse to run, I believe that they do need the SDK.

Comment: YouWave isn't something I'm looking for. What I need is program that will enable me to run website through multiple point of views (iPhone pov, Android pov, Opera  Mini under few OSes and etc). Thank you for your answer!